# Wordpress Plugin - WooCommerce - Hide a product if

Tags: wordpress, plugins, woocommerce, hide, product

my question is: I have 2 products configured in my WooCommerce plugin for WordPress.

Now I want "hide" a product if the user hasn't bought another one (and make it unavailable)

For example: I have the 1st product and the 2nd product
if I buy the 1st product, I'm able to buy the 2nd one, but if I don't buy the 1st one, the 2nd must not be available (the "Buy" button need disappear from the 2nd product)

Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: Try [Product Dependecies](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-product-dependencies/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm this is not quite what you are asking for but this is a premium option that allows you to add rules to the display products. Its probably worth a look. https://docs.woothemes.com/document/woocommerce-conditional-content/

You could also try working backwards off something like this depending on your skill level. https://gist.github.com/codearachnid/9259601

Comment: The problem is that I can't hide products because someone can buy the 1st product and the 2nd one together, but not the 2nd one without the 1st

It's hard to explain...

Comment: Hmm I think with the conditional logic plugin you can make it so that the second product is only visible if the first one is in the cart.. It may be worth hoping on support with them and seeing if that plugin would fulfill your needs.

Comment: Can you confirm that if I buy that plugin then I can do what I'm asking? For $49 I need to be sure that is what I'm looking for...

Comment: I do not know for sure, but they have great support. I also believe they would offer a refund if it did not fufill your needs.

Comment: I haven't bought it yet, I've solved the problem myself :)